# How to make LDAP user ID case sensitive in Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cas, openldap, case-sensitive

I have configured Open LDAP and Microsoft Active Directory for my system. I have observed that OpenLDAP and Microsoft-AD both are case insensitive to the user id. To make case sensitive login for OpenLDAP users, I have configured  **"p:filter="uid:caseExactmatch:=%u"** which works fine but for Microsoft-AD **"p:filter="sAMAccountName:caseExactMatch:=%u"** doesn't work.

How can I make the AD users login with case-sensitive user id ?

Comment: I don't think you can, `sAMAccountName`, like almost all other attributes is case-insensitive on filtering.

Answer (score 0):

As Mathias has already suggested, Active Directory is "case aware" not "case sensitive" for almost all attributes. Which means it will respect the cases you enter (E.G "John Smith" rather than "john smith") but pays no attention to that case when filtering.
Further detail on this can be found in [this technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx).